# Will the vote still count for that tag?

Tags: discussion

If someone answers a question, under tag `discussion`, then that answer is downvoted once, so he/she has (-1) on that answer now.

After some time someone upvotes the answer and now he/she has (0) votes on it with +8 reputation. Will that upvote count toward getting the bronze `discussion` tag, or since it's (0) then he/she won't get that upvote, won't be counted toward getting that tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downvote cancels the upvote.

The tag badges are awarded as a function of the *net* number of votes (along with a minimum number of questions answered on that tag). Note further that this net number is not subject to daily reputation capping.

Comment: How are the upvotes not subject to the daily reputation cap? That sounds like they would earn reputation beyond the cap... I think you mean that even if you've reached the max daily reputation from upvotes, any more upvotes still count towards badges?

Comment: @Xen2050 yes, the tag badge algorithm does not care for reputation, only total score.